# Update Error Oledb C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

Nao consigo usar o comando UPDATE mais de uma vez.

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xyqp6rA4Rk3AvneFaUlqk6AVvjQjbtSi/view?usp=drivesdk)

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/190WFQ0cxGWYJw2aO66xBNvOsNftY7CAk/view?usp=drivesdk)

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-XS3NeZm7cU0_4Pi7r2fY4dCNNAjCKtf/view?usp=drivesdk)

Por exemplo, quando eu realizo o update no id 43, da certo. Porém quando vou tentar finalizar o 44, ele não finaliza, mas o 43 que pega o update..

Código:

Int att,index;

Private void DataGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventsArgs e)
{

```
   if(e.RowIndex &gt;= 0)
   {

         Index = e.RowIndex;                                               
         att = Convert.ToInt32(DataGrid.Rows[Index].Cells[0].Value);
```

}
  }
//quando clico numa célula, Att recebe o número que está //dentro dela, no caso correspondente ao ID na database tb. E index recebe o índice da linha.

```
private void Btnfnz_Click(objetc sender, EventArgs e)
{
     If(index >=0)
     {
          var linha = DataGrid1.Rows[index];
          cn.Connection = Conexão.conectar();
          cn.CommandText = "UPDATE Atendimento SET HorarioOut = ' " + Txthr.Text + " ' WHERE ID=@att";
          cn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@att",att);
          cn.ExecuteNonQuery();
          cn.Connection = Conexão.desconectar();
     }
     else 
     {
           MessageBox.Show("Lista vazia!");
     }
     Refreshatt(); //Carrega o datagrid com dados do banco dados, onde horarioOut estiver em branco.
}
```

Tudo funciona de Boa, porém quando tento fazer um novo update, ele até faz, porém no msm ID, fica fixado no primeiro ID que fiz o update.

Comment: Falta o esquema do banco de dados e um exemplo do sql update que você está usando

Comment: Desculpa, não estava conseguindo. Agora foi, obrigado!

Comment: Coloque seu código como texto o editor tem ferramentas para isso. Use imagens a menos que seja necessário

Comment: Onde está a atribuição de `att`?

Comment: Pronto coloquei o código, é que estou sem internet no computador..

Comment: Declarei a variável int att;  entre as funções, dentro do form...